# Need clarity on which component in default pipeline modifies lemma_ on Doc and need suggestions for improving spacy throughput

Tags: python, spacy

2 questions:

I am using

```
' '.join([word.lemma_ for word in nlp(word_chunk)])
```

to lemmatise a word chunk. I want to reduce the latency of nlp method call. I am considering disabling some components of the nlp pipeline. This doc doesn't mention which component modifies lemma_ attribute so that I can just retain those components in my pipeline and discard the later components.

We are using py spark and spacy for parallelly processing large amounts of text data. But still we are not happy with the throughput. I am trying to reduce spacy call latencies to improve throughput. What else do you guys suggest? Should I explore using nlp.pipe over nlp in our py spark cluster? Or should I consider running pyspark with gpu as spacy is a pipeline of neural network predictions?

Detailed elaboration of point 1(Optional Read)
I will start by giving some background on the problem I am trying to solve.
We are using spacy to process large amounts of text data to extract insights from it.
We are using spacy with its default pipeline for multiple tasks:

identifying different sentences in a text using Doc.sents
Given a word, identifying it's lemma using

```
' '.join([word.lemma_ for word in SpacyUtils.nlp(word_chunk)])
```

Doc noun chunks to get noun chunks in a sentence
Doc tag to get POS tag.
Doc dep to get dependency parsing of a sentence.
For each of the 5 tasks above, I am using spacy with default pipeline. I want to alter the pipeline for each of the tasks above to reduce time taken for each of the tasks.

This document neatly summarises which components of default pipeline creates which attributes in Doc object.
My strategy is to only retain parts of pipeline which are relevant for the task.

For tasks 1,3,5 which require sents,noun_chunks and dep, I am retaining tagger, parser and discarding ner.
For tasks 4, I am retaining tagger alone.
For task 2, which is the most frequently used task, i am not able to decide which part of pipelines to retain as it's not clearly mentioned which component creates attribute Doc lemma